# Can't find the target specified for makefile

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, makefile

First of all I apologize if I'm asking silly question. Because I'm actually out of unix for 8 months. I have installed GMP, libpcap, and Gengetopt which are required to install another application. I used the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev libpcap-dev gengetopt
```

After that I tried

```
cd src; make
```

But it shows that

```
make: ***No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

My current directory is `home` directory.

My questions are:

1. Are those packages not installed properly?
2. Is my makefile target directory wrong?

Comment: Sounds like `src` is empty, or at least doesn't contain a Makefile.

Comment: i don't have root access. i looked in the server and found the packages are installed in /usr directory.

Comment: The packages are not the problem. Installing packages will certainly not populate a `src` directory in your home directory. Do you want to build these packages from source? Then try `apt-get source libgmp3`; but the source directory will be called something like `libgmp3-2.34`, not `src`.

Comment: Anyway, your question seems to imply that "another application" is what you want to compile, and that its sources are in `/home/you/src`. If that is not the case, please edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the explanation. I just need little more time to figure out exact problem and then i'll edit my post here.

Comment: Thanks finally i figured out there was a problem with the src directory. Now it works fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have any Makefile in the current directory when you are entering make. Have you made sure you got one there ?

Comment: Need to mention that I don't have root permission. I'm a user of a webserver. Is that causing because of that? I can see the packages are installed in /usr directory.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application, but quite often you will have to run `configure` before you can actually build the application. You do not need root permission for the `make` step, but for the `make install` step which usually installs the binary globally.

`make install` is not necessary, but a matter of convenience, so you can still run the application in directory in which it was built.

so try `cd src; ./configure && make`

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't have to run the configure. I solved the problem by fixing the location of the directory src.